# Creating a numpy array and then sorting array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have been encountering a problem that I can't seem to solve I need to take a list of strings and calculate some values and then add the relevant string and the relevant integer to a numpy array. I've been told to create the numpy array of zeroes first as it will be of a known length so I can do that. My problem is how do I iteratively add each string to the first column (names) and each value (labels) to the second and then sort the full array alphabetically by the first column

```
fileCount = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(inputDirectory)])
labelArray = np.zeros(shape = (fileCount,2))
arrayInsertCounter = 0

for label, subDirectories in enumerate(inputDirectory):

  subDirPath = os.path.join(inputDirectory, subDirectories)

  for name in subDirPath:

    labelArray[arrayInsertCounter] = [name,label]
    arrayInsertCounter += 1
```

Comment: Why are you using numpy for this? It looks like a regular python list would be much easier. Convert it to an array at the end if you need an array.

Comment: Initialize with `Object` dtype in `np.zeros` for such mixed dtype data.

Comment: @roganjosh I have to have it as a numpy array input later on in my code, do you think I could sort it as a list here and then convert it to a numpy array later?

Comment: You absolutely could do that. Just build a list and convert it to an array. You're not getting any speed benefits from using numpy the way you are, it's running in Python time because of the `for` loop. Not sure whether it's faster to sort in numpy or python for your list, you'd have to test and convert before/after sorting as appropriate.

Comment: Great thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in `numpy` using a structured array

```
import numpy as np

labels = list(map(''.join, zip(*3*((chr(ord('a')+(19*i)%24) for i in range(24)),))))
numbers = np.arange(8)

dt = np.dtype([('label', object), ('value', int)])

table = np.empty((8,), dtype = dt)

table['label'] = labels
table['value'] = numbers

print(table)
table.sort()
print(table)
```

Output:

```
#[('ato', 0) ('jex', 1) ('sni', 2) ('dwr', 3) ('mhc', 4) ('vql', 5)
# ('gbu', 6) ('pkf', 7)]
#[('ato', 0) ('dwr', 3) ('gbu', 6) ('jex', 1) ('mhc', 4) ('pkf', 7)
# ('sni', 2) ('vql', 5)]
```

**Edit:** How to access individual records:

```
table[2] = 'new label', 1000
table
# array([('ato',    0), ('dwr',    3), ('new label', 1000), ('jex',    1),
#        ('mhc',    4), ('pkf',    7), ('sni',    2), ('vql',    5)],
#       dtype=[('label', 'O'), ('value', '<i8')])
```